# What environment entries do I need to pass sys.path to a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, sys.path

NB OS is currently W10.

See [this](https://askto.pro/question/how-to-pass-sys-path-in-subprocess).

To my amazement, this works:

```
subprocess.run(['python', 'subprocess_file.py'], env={**os.environ, 'PYTHONPATH':';'.join(sys.path)})
```

When I say "it works", what I mean is that if a new entry (i.e. path) is added to `sys.path` in the calling process, it can then be found in the subprocess's `sys.path`. Not only that, but it is then possible for the subprocess to `import` from this added path, without any difficulties.

However, I find that if I don't use `PYTHONPATH` in this way, or if I omit `**os.environ`, then `subprocess.run` fails to run. In the latter case, seemingly failing silently, without raising an exception.

I have a couple of questions: presumably not all the entries in `os.environ` are needed for this to work, so which ones *are* needed?

And is using `PYTHONPATH` in this way the only way to smuggle `sys.path` into the subprocess? I never use `PYTHONPATH` in the course of things so ideally I'd like to avoid it here.

PS I presume there is no way to smuggle `sys.modules` (or selected modules from it) into a subprocess?

Comment: I wish we knew more about your specific situation; generally, having to muck about with `sys.path` is a sign that Something Else Is Wrong. Your `subprocess.run` command passes all environment variables to the subprocess *by default* (that's how environment variables work), so what you're doing right now is the correct way to add a new environment variable to the subprocess.

Comment: I didn't check documentation but I expect it uses `os.environ` as default when you don't set `env=`. And when you set only `PYTHONPATH` then process doesn't get `os.environ` and this makes problem. Different processes may need different values from `os.environ` and you would have to check this on your own. But it is much simpler to send all `os.environ` instead of checking which values it really need.

Comment: @larsks I just double-checked: if I execute `run` without the `env` argument, and print out the contents of `sys.path` in the subprocess, I definitely observe that the path elements added during the calling process are NOT present. This is a very basic pair of scripts, made just to test this point. Are you asserting that `sys.path` is **meant** to be passed to the subprocess? Have you got this from the docs or from experience? If from the docs could you point me where?

Comment: What? No, I'm asserting that what you have in your question is the correct way to pass sys.path to a subprocess via the PYTONPATH variable.

Comment: OK thanks. As a matter of interest, to your knowledge, *is* this documented somewhere? I just found the linked page by searching... I read virtually all of the subprocess docs page but couldn't find anything.